# How to loop through xml table row and access the column values by attribute names

Tags: php, xml, laravel

This is an extract of the data in my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1052" ?>
<atp xmlns:atp="http://xml.alamte.com/atp">
  <transaction> 
    <table name="POS:Plus">
      <row id="6">
        <col name="LongDescription">TeTera Pinot </col>
        <col name="TillDescription">TeTera Pinot</col>
        <col name="TouchscreenDescription">TeTera Peroni</col>
      </row>
     </table>
  </transaction>
</atp>
```

Code

```
$data = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string(preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\xFF]/', '', Storage::get('xmls/imports/' . $filename)))), TRUE);

if (isset($data['transaction']['table'])) {
    $tables = $data['transaction']['table'];

    foreach($tables as $check_table){
        if(isset($check_table['@attributes']['name']) && $check_table['@attributes']['name'] == 'STOCKPRO:PLUs')
        $stock_plus_table = $check_table;
        if(isset($check_table['@attributes']['name']) && $check_table['@attributes']['name'] == 'POS:Plus')
        $pos_plus_table = $check_table;
        if(isset($check_table['@attributes']['name']) && $check_table['@attributes']['name'] == 'POS:PLUPrices')
        $pos_plu_prices_table = $check_table;
    }


    if (isset($pos_plu_prices_table) && isset($pos_plu_prices_table['row'])) {
        $plu_prods = $pos_plu_prices_table['row'];

        //working on POS:PLUPrices table for price updation
        foreach ($plu_prods as $plu_prod) {
            if(isset($plu_prod['col']))
                $plu_prod = $plu_prod['col'];
            else
                $plu_prod = $plu_prods['col'];
                $plu = $plu_prod[0];
                $price_level = $plu_prod[3];
                $price = (float) preg_replace('/[^0-9\.]/ui', '', $plu_prod[4]);
               

            //checking if plu exists in our database
            if (Products::where('plu', $plu)->first() && ($price_level == 0 || $price_level == 1)) {

                $product = Products::where('plu', $plu)->first();

                if (isset($stock_plus_table)) {
                  $plu_child_prods = $stock_plus_table['row'];

                    //working on STOCKPRO:PLUs table for child products stock updation
                    foreach ($plu_child_prods as $enter_item_2) {
                        $enter_item_2_store = $enter_item_2;
                        if(isset($enter_item_2['col']))
                        $enter_item_2 = $enter_item_2['col'];
                        else
                        $enter_item_2 = $plu_child_prods['col'];

                        //checking if this item is child plu of the current plu
                        if ($enter_item_2[27] == $plu) {
                            $product_st = Products::where('plu', $enter_item_2_store['@attributes']['id'])->first();
                            if ($product_st) {
                                $product_st->parent = $product->id;
                                $product_st->pack = (int) $enter_item_2[28];
                                $product_st->save();
                            }

                            if ($product_st && (int) $enter_item_2[28] != 0) {
                                $product_st->stock = floor($product->stock / (int) $enter_item_2[28]);
                                $product_st->save();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                //updating prices of plu
                $pro_price = ProductPrices::where('product_id', $product->id)->orderBy('id', 'Desc')->first();

                if ($pro_price) {
                    if ($price_level == 0) {
                        $pro_price->luc = $price;
                    } else if ($price_level == 1) {
                        $pro_price->price = $price;
                    }
                    $pro_price->save();
                }
                $trini_update_products .= $product->id . ',';
                $trini_update_count++;

            } else {

                //checking if plu is not availbale in our database
                if (!Products::where('plu', $plu)->first()) {

                    $deleted = "True";
                    $group = '';
                    $subcategory = '';

                    //creating new plu in database
                    $product = new Products();
                    
                    if (isset($pos_plus_table)) {
                        $plu_match_prods = $pos_plus_table['row'];

                        //working on POS:Plus table for product name information
                        foreach ($plu_match_prods as $enter_item_1) {
                        
                            if (isset($enter_item_1['@attributes']['id']) && $enter_item_1['@attributes']['id'] == $plu) {  
                
                                $touch_screen_description = $enter_item_1[2];
                                $group = $enter_item_1[5];
                                $deleted = $enter_item_1[7];
                                $product->plu = $plu;
                                $product->name = $touch_screen_description;
                                $subcategory = SubCategories::where('product_group', $group)->orderBy('id', 'Desc')->first();
                                $product->category_id = $subcategory['category_id'];
                                $product->subcategory_id = $subcategory['id'];                                                   
                                
                            }                                           
                        }   
                    }
                



                    if (isset($stock_plus_table)) {
                        $plu_match2_prods = $stock_plus_table['row'];

                        //working on STOCKPRO:PLUs table for stock information
                        foreach ($plu_match2_prods as $enter_item_2) {
                            if (isset($enter_item_2['@attributes']['id']) && $enter_item_2['@attributes']['id'] == $plu) {
                                $enter_item_2 = $enter_item_2['col'];
                                //$barcode = $enter_item_2[1];
                                $stock = $enter_item_2[14];
                                $product->stock = $stock < 0 ? 0 : $stock;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    //checking if triniteq have deleted this plu from their side
                    if ($deleted != "True") {
                        $product->status = '0';
                        $product->xml = 1;
                        $product->plu = $plu;
                        $product->file = $filename;
                        $product->category_id = $subcategory['category_id'];
                        $product->subcategory_id = $subcategory['id'];
                        $product->save();
                        $pro_price = new ProductPrices();
                        $pro_price->product_id = $product->id;
                        if ($price_level == 0) {
                            $pro_price->luc = $price;
                        } else if ($price_level == 1) {
                            $pro_price->price = $price;
                        }

                        $pro_price->save();

                        //taking record of all plu affected by this cron folder updation
                        $trini_update_products .= $product->id . ',';
                        $trini_update_count++;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        //taking record of all files processed in this cron
        $trini_update_files .= $filename . ',';
    }

    return redirect()->back()->with('msg', "$trini_update_count inventories Updated Successfully");
} else {
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['Invalid XML format']);
}

}
```

I am able to access the column values using array indexes, but i would like to access the column values using the column name attributes instead.

For example  is an array, i can access 'TeTera Peroni' using row[2]
But the problem is i want to access 'TeTera Peroni' using name="TouchscreenDescription" because TouchscreenDescription is not always at row[2] it may change its position

Please help

Comment: Show the code you have to process this please. Makes an answer so much easier

Comment: Or Read [Example #5 Using attributes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) On the PHP Manual Page

Comment: Thanks Riggs I have updated my question with code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xpath expressions allow you to fetch specific nodes from the XML. However only `DOMXpath::evaluate()` supports expressions that return scalar values.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

// iterate the 'POS:Plus' table element(s)
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/atp/transaction/table[@name="POS:Plus"]') as $table) {
    $records = [];
    $tableName = $table->getAttribute('name');
    // for each row child element
    foreach ($xpath->evaluate('row', $table) as $row) {
        // fetch row values
        $records[] = [
          'Id' => $row->getAttribute('id'),
          'LongDescription' => $xpath->evaluate('string(col[@name="LongDescription"])', $row),
          'TillDescription' => $xpath->evaluate('string(col[@name="TillDescription"])', $row),
          'TouchscreenDescription' => $xpath->evaluate('string(col[@name="TouchscreenDescription"])', $row),
        ];
    }
    var_dump($tableName, $records);
}
// next table
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/atp/transaction/table[@name="POS:PLUPrices"]') as $table) {
    // ...
}
// ...
```

Output:

```
string(8) "POS:Plus"
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Id"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["LongDescription"]=>
    string(13) "TeTera Pinot "
    ["TillDescription"]=>
    string(12) "TeTera Pinot"
    ["TouchscreenDescription"]=>
    string(13) "TeTera Peroni"
  }
}
```

You're defining an XML namespace in the snippet but you never use it. If working with a namepace you would need to register it for the Xpath expressions. Here is an example using `http://xml.alamte.com/atp` as the default namespace.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<atp xmlns="http://xml.alamte.com/atp">
  <transaction> 
    <table name="POS:Plus">...</table>
  </transaction>
</atp>
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$xpath->registerNamespace('atp', 'http://xml.alamte.com/atp');

// iterate the 'POS:Plus' table elements
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/atp:atp/atp:transaction/atp:table[@name="POS:Plus"]') as $table) {
    $tableName = $table->getAttribute('name');
    var_dump($tableName);
}
```

Output:

```
string(8) "POS:Plus"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, had found a hacky way around it, but this seems to be the best way